# CPP: Writing gmail Mail Auto Reply program in CPP

Tags: c++, c, gmail

I have been away with my smart phone for some times which used to help me replying mails on the go. and during this time I felt a need of writing a CPP program which will be keep running on my desktop at home and will reply my gmail inbox messages based upon some matching patters in the Subject line or in the Text lines.

I want to write a CPP program on UNIX platform which will be keep checking 
1) if there is any unread mail in my gmail inbox. 
2) Search for a pattern in that mail 
3) If pattern matched it will reply to the mail with some fixed text message.

I dont know how and which gmail APIs can be used to integrate this in a CPP program? I found that VB.NET has some APIs by which we can achieve this. I am a CPP lover so I want to write in CPP.

Please guide me how can I proceed ? Thanks.

Comment: firstly, are you looking for an "out of the office" responce? this is builtin gmail already :-P. Next, if you insist on c++ have a look at http://www.vmime.org/

Comment: @Najzero OOO is something which replies to everybody. I need such service which will only reply when some specific strings are found in the texts/ or subjects. Thanks for the link, I am reading it.

Comment: for a start, c++ (if that you mean with cpp) sounds like a wrong tool to do it

Comment: @BЈовић What you think is the right tool other that C++ ? what about C?

Comment: @Najzero I have downloaded the vmime library 0.9.1 in my MAC. Could you please assist me how it can be installed, so that I can access it in my terminal c++ programs ?

Comment: @CodeCodeCode if you don't know how to link libraries I am not sure if you should really code an email sending thingy in  c++. There are so many tutorials in the net, I just took the first one I found from oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/linkinglibraries-396782.html . If you are using visiual studio, you might wanna google up "visual studio use libraries" ( or any other IDE you are fond with )

Answer (score 2):

CPP will do (but will definitely take some to get all the things into working state).

First what you need to do is to follow the POP3 & SMTP (Post Office Protocol 3 & Simple Mail Transport Protocol) which is used by mail client to read out email meta-data (how many new mails, how many unread) and send new email using mail server.

You need to get atleast basic idea of how to get -

1. email metadata from inbox using POP3
2. download them (for pattern search on the text body) using POP3
3. reply to them using SMTP

Also you will need encryption support TLS for security.

Fortunately there is a great library which you have used - libcurl.
You can use libcurl (built with openssl & openldap) to send reply to mail very easily.

The remaining bits are 1 & 2, which I believe can be done very with libcurl.

The best part is, libcurl is very reliable and fast (takes ~1-2 secs for auth, TLS setup & sending the mail to server).

The worst part - linking and linking (openssl, openldap, libcurl ...).

Anyways hope this helps & good luck with the journey :).

regards,